# Tensor chain complex with non-vanishing homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Is there an example of a chain complex $(C_{\ast},d)$ with trivial homology, such that the chain complex $C_\ast\otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has non-vanishing homology in every degree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. First take the exact sequence $ 0 \to \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/ 2 \Bbb Z \to 0$ where the first map is multiplication by $2$. 
Tensoring by $\Bbb Z/ 2\Bbb Z$ create homology in degree 1. Now, infinite sum of such shifted exact sequence (considered as complex) does the trick. More formally, let $C$ be the complex $$C := \dots \to 0 \to 0 \to \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/ 2 \Bbb Z \to 0 \to 0 \to \dots $$

The complex $D = \bigoplus_{n \in \Bbb Z} C[n]$ does the trick, where for a complex $C$, the complex $C[d]$ is defined by $C[n]_i = C_{n+i}$ and similarly for the differential.

Comment: Any short exact sequence which yields a non-exact sequence after applying the right-exact functor $-\otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ works. Another such ses is $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$.